Laravel vite : get the versioned url of my JavaScript file
with laravel vite, how can i get the versioned url of my javascript file.
Do you have any ideas for implementing any specific versioning for my project.

vite will hash your assets when you build your assets.
if this asset's hash name changes it is new version.
it would work fine.
but if you want to get manifest hash, use this code:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Vite;

Vite::manifestHash();

if you want to get url with hashed name for a specific asset, use this code:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Vite;

Vite::asset('resources/scss/app.scss');

doc : https://laravel.com/api/11.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Vite.html
